# How to resolve "unknown user 'elasticsearch' in statoverride file" error?

Tags: dpkg

I have been trying to install Elastic Search, I have downloaded the the `elasticsearch-2.3.4.deb` file. When I try to use the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-1.7.2.deb
```

It outputs this error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: unknown user 'elasticsearch' in statoverride file
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 21):

In my case, following these steps worked:

- Begin by completely uninstalling any Elasticsearch instances on your machine:

  ```
  apt remove --purge elasticsearch
  apt autoremove
  ```
- Then, open the `/var/lib/dpkg/statoverride` file in your editor and remove lines mentioning the `elasticsearch` user.

It's not an ideal solution because it involves manually editing files which are normally modified only by `dpkg` itself, but running `dpkg-reconfigure` and `apt --reinstall install` didn't work for me; this was a last resort.

Comment: 'apt autoremove' was not necessary, editing statoverride did the trick

Comment: @user1007727 Thanks! Good to have an extra datapoint. I'm leaving in the `autoremove` invocation anyway because it was required for me (IIRC), and it helps unclutter the system worst case.

Answer (score 9):

open the file

```
/var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
```

you should see something like:

```
root elasticsearch 755 /var/log/elasticsearch
```

or

```
root elasticsearch 755 /var/lib/elasticsearch
```

if so, run dpkg-statoverride --remove:

```
dpkg-statoverride --remove /var/log/elasticsearch
dpkg-statoverride --remove /var/lib/elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 2):

I just need

```
sudo dpkg-statoverride --remove /var/lib/elasticsearch
sudo dpkg-statoverride --remove /var/log/elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue for me was that I renamed the default user to fall in line with my naming scheme on my server.

I resolved this issue by editing the

```
/var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
```

file and replacing the old name with the new.  No need to uninstall the application.